# snmpwalk not showing the privite MIB

Tags: net-snmp

Hi I installed SNMP on centOS and here is my snmp.conf

```
agentAddress udp:161

com2sec me localhost       public
com2sec nms 192.168.1.8       public

group   AllGroup        v2c             me
group   AllGroup        v2c             nms
group   AllGroup        v1             me
group   AllGroup        v1             nms

view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.11.19
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.2.1.11.29
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9
view    AllView         included        1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10

access  AllGroup        ""      any     noauth  exact   AllView         none    none

syslocation Myserver
syscontact Admin <admin@admin.com>

proc httpd
proc mysqld

disk /tmp 290000
disk /var 2000000
disk /home 18600000

load 14 10 10
```

When I run

```
snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public
```

It shows

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (37590) 0:06:15.90
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Admin <admin@admin.com>
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: server.admin.om
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: Myserver
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpInTraps.0 = Counter32: 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpOutTraps.0 = Counter32: 0
```

But the private OCD not appearing

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2 
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9 
1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10
```

But when I run them specific via

```
snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public 1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2
```

The private OCD MIB do show up as per the configuration.

How can I make the private OCDs shows with

```
snmpwalk -v 1 localhost -c public
```

??

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

From [the `snmpwalk` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpwalk):

> If no OID argument is present, snmpwalk will search the subtree rooted at SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 (including any MIB object values from other MIB modules, that are defined as lying within this subtree)

`SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2` is 1.3.6.1.2.1; your private tree simply isn't part of the "default" selection.

If you wish to request specific information, request specific information.